# Examining Map variable in this java project source code

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I'm trying to understand the following code, in a class called Display.java:

```
    Map<String,Object> context = (Map<String,Object>) globalSession.get("cascadas.ace.context");
    if(context != null) {
      dresscode = (String) context.get("dresscode");
      hobby = (String) context.get("hobby");
    }
    if ((hobby == null) || (dresscode == null)) {
        SystemConfiguration.getInstance().getLog().warning("Advertisement display: dresscode and/or hobby not available, no image will be displayed.");
    }
```

What's happening is that there's a GUI window that allows one to choose radio buttons for both dress-code and hobby. But somehow when I add in another dummy radio button in the program text(in a class that's in the same folder as Display.java, called ContextSimulatorGUI , it does not even show the GUI window.. , and I see the following in the console:

```
Advertisement display: dresscode and/or hobby not available, no image will be displayed."
```

Regarding the `globalSession` variable..  it's a "Session" object; in the project there's a class called `Session`, which looks like so:

/*
 * ACE Autonomic Toolkit
 * (a.k.a CASCADAS ACE Toolkit)
 * 
 * Created by CASCADAS project Work Package 1:
 *  - Budapest University of Technology and Economics
 *  - Fraunhofer Institut FOKUS
 *  - Telecom Italia Labs
 *  - University of Kassel
 *  - University of Modena and Reggio Emilia
 *
 * More information is available on:
 *  - http://acetoolkit.sourceforge.net

```
 *  - http://cascadas-project.org
 *
 * The authors would like to acknowledge the European Commission 
 * for funding the Integrated Project CASCADAS Component-ware for 
 * Autonomic, Situation-aware Communications, And Dynamically 
 * Adaptable Services (FET Proactive Initiative, IST-2004-2.3.4 
 * Situated and Autonomic Communications) within the 6th IST Framework 
 * Program. The authors also wish to thank other project Partners for 
 * the fruitful cooperation within the project.
 */

package cascadas.ace.session;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Interface describing the session context.
 */
// TODO: use generics for type safety stuff?
public interface Session extends Serializable {

        /**
         * Returns the name of the SessionContext.
         *
         * @return the name
         */
        public String getName();


        /**
         * Removes the key-value pair from the session.
         * @param key param name
         */
        public void remove(String key);


        /**
         * Returns the current state.
         *
         * @return curretn state
         */
//        public State getState(); 


        /**
         * Sets the current state.
         *
         * @param s the state
         */
 //       public void setState(State s);


        /**
         * Returns the contract with the specified id.
         *
         * @param contract id
         * @return contract
         * @throws SessionContextNotFoundException if contract is not found
         */
//        public Contract getContract(String id) throws SessionNotFoundException; 


        /**
         * Adds a contract with the given id. Id must be unique.
         *
         * @param s the state
         */
//        public void addContract(String id, Contract c);


        /**
         * Returns all contracts.
         *
         * @return id-->contract map
         */
//        public Map<String,Contract> getAllContracts();


        /**
         * Puts a piece of data to the session context.
         * Overwrites existing data with teh same name.
         *
         * @param id name of the data
         * @param value value of the data
         */
        public void put( String id, Object value ) throws SessionException;


        /**
         * Puts an integer value into the session context.
         *
         * @param id name
         * @param value value
         */
        public void put ( String id, int        value );


        /**
         * Puts a double value into the session context.
         *
         * @param id name
         * @param value value
         */
        public void put ( String id, double     value );


        /**
         * Puts a float into the session context.
         *
         * @param id name
         * @param value value
         */
       public void put ( String id, float      value );


        /**
         * Puts a long value into the session context.
         *
         * @param id name
         * @param value value
         */
        public void put ( String id, long       value );


        /**
         * Puts a short value into the session context.
         *
         * @param id name
         * @param value value
         */
        public void put ( String id, short      value );


        /**
         * Puts a char into the session context.
         *
         * @param id name
         * @param value value
         */
        public void put ( String id, char       value );


        /**
         * Puts a boolean value into the session context.
         *
         * @param id name
         * @param value value
         */
        public void put ( String id, boolean    value );




        /**
         * Returns the matching data from the session context.
         *
         * @param id name of the data
         * @return the data as an Object or null if not found
         */
        public Object get (String id) ;


        /**
         * Returns the matching data from the session context.
         *
         * @param id name of the data
         * @throws cascadas.ace.reasoner.SessionContextException 
         *              if an error occurs
         * @return the data as an integer or 0 if not found
         */
        public int getInt ( String id) throws SessionException;


        /**
         * Returns the matching data from the session context.
         *
         * @param id name of the data
         * @throws cascadas.ace.reasoner.SessionContextException 
         *              if an error occurs
         * @return the data as a double
         */
        public double getDouble ( String id) throws SessionException;


        /**
         * Returns the matching data from the session context.
         *
         * @param id name of the data
         * @throws cascadas.ace.reasoner.SessionContextException 
         *              if an error occurs
         * @return the data as a float
         */
        public float getFloat ( String id) throws SessionException;


        /**
         * Returns the matching data from the session context.
         *
         * @param id name of the data
         * @throws cascadas.ace.reasoner.SessionContextException 
         *              if an error occurs
         * @return the data as a long
         */
        public long getLong ( String id) throws SessionException;


        /**
         * Returns the matching data from the session context.
         *
         * @param id name of the data
         * @throws cascadas.ace.reasoner.SessionContextException 
         *              if an error occurs
         * @return the data as a short
         */
        public short getShort ( String id) throws SessionException;


        /**
         * Returns the matching data from the session context.
         *
         * @param id name of the data
         * @throws cascadas.ace.reasoner.SessionContextException 
         *              if an error occurs
         * @return the data as a char
         */
        public char getChar ( String id) throws SessionException;


        /**
         * Returns the matching data from the session context.
         *
         * @param id name of the data
         * @throws cascadas.ace.reasoner.SessionContextException 
         *              if an error occurs
         * @return the data as a boolean
         */
        public boolean getBoolean ( String id) throws SessionException;


         /**
         * Returns the matching data from the session context.
         *
         * @param id name of the data
         * @throws cascadas.ace.reasoner.SessionContextException 
         *              if an error occurs
         * @return the data as a String
         */
        public String getString ( String id) throws SessionException;


        /**
         * Returns all data as a set.
         * @return all data in the session context
         */
        public Map<String,Object>  getAllData();

        /**
         * Sets the ace name (for debug messages).
         * @param aceName ace name
         */
        public void setAceName(String aceName);

}
```

..etc (btw I know that source is a little sloppy, but it's some open-source project, not my code).

So to conclude, I mainly want to *understand* the code at the very top, the bottom stuff is the context. I hope this wasn't confusing - I appreciate any tips or advice.

Comment: Session does not even have a get method... What don't you understand?

Comment: @assylias - Hmm, sorry about that - I hadn't posted all of it. Anyway, I'll just keep digging